# passing a record from one function to another and then assigning values there in Clojure

Tags: clojure, record

I just started learning Clojure. I have a function where I create a record with keys. I now wish to pass the record to another function where I can bind some data to the labels. I tried

```
(defn structure[]
(let [record1 (defrecord rec1 [field1 field2])] record1))

(defn init-structure[record]
(def initialized (record. name 23)))

(defn -main[]
(println (init-structure structure)))
```

I want the output to be `{:field1 name :field2 23}`. However, clojure throws me a "unable to resolve classname: record" error....how do I proceed from here ?

Comment: You created a new record type named `rec1` but later are trying to call `record.`

Comment: I recommend against using records at this point in time. Use maps instead. Using records "freezes" your program in unnecessary ways. One can switch from maps to records later. Also, use Clojure spec and Clojure test extensively.

Answer (score 1):

You created a new record type named `rec1` but later are trying to call `record.`

Also, you are calling `init-structure` with a reference to `structure`, which is probably not what you want.
In general, special forms or functions starting with `def` should be used outside of functions.

Here's an example:

```
(defrecord rec1 [field1 field2])

(defn init-structure []
  (rec1. "name" 23))

(defn -main []
  (println (init-structure)))
```

And typically you would use a REPL to play with the code and not try to use `-main` all the time. That's one of the fun things of Clojure. Write a function or two, evaluated in in the REPL, call it and see if it does the things it should do.

Comment: Thanks a lot..I modified your answer and it worked...is it not possible to send the record I create in a function as a parameter to another?  I was returning record1 from structure and I was thinking of using it in init-structure...

Comment: Also I was trying to do something like (init-structure (structure))...so that the value returned by structure could be used by init-structure...

Comment: You didn't return a record from `structure`, you returned the result of  `defrecord`, not the record itself. `defrecord` returns a class object. Defrecord also creates various functions to create actual records.

i.e. defrecord is actually more like a type declaration, not creating an object of a specific type